# how to set onClickListener on words of string in a textField in compose UI

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-ui

Actually  I'm  developing an social-media  app where I want that my user can mention more than one  user in between of their compliment string just like in Instagram comment section...
on which if someOne tap  of their username... it'll lead them to the particular user's profile
[desired result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfOgk.png)

I'm well aware of the use of buildAnnotationString{} where we can play with textStyle but is there anyway to set onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

you have to create ClickableText not simple Text.

```
ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("ClickableText"),
        onClick = {
           // perform here your action
        },
    )
```